# unable to get desired precision of the output from division of 2 integers in R

Tags: r

Iam dividing two numbers in R. The numerator is a big integer ( ranges in millions) divided by a 13.00001
It is taking 13.000001 as 13 and the output that comes is limited to only 1 decimal place.
I require the output to be uptil 2 decimal places which is not happening.
I tried round, format and as.numeric but it is fruitless
round is not giving anything (round(divison,1)
format(nsmall=2) makes it upto 2 decimal places but converts it into character
as.numeric reconverts it from character but the 2 decimal places are replaced by 1 decimal place
Is there any way that I can get 2 decimal places when I divide an integer with a number like 13.000001?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Be careful not to confuse output with internal precision:

```
x <- 13e7/13.000001

sprintf("%10.20f",x)
#[1] "9999999.23076928965747356415"

sprintf("%10.10f",x*13)
#[1] "129999990.0000007600"

sprintf("%10.10f",x*13.000001)
#[1] "129999999.9999999851"
```

Differences to the expected output are due to the limited [floating point precision](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9508558/1412059).